# Opening Chrome with Launcher in 14.04 doesn't take focus

Tags: launcher, google-chrome, chromium, focus

Using the Launcher to open Chrome (Super, chrome, enter) does not take focus from what ever application was running previously.

Kinda defeating the purpose of the Launcher.

At the same time, the text cursor is 'alive'/blinking in both chrome in the search bar and any previous application.

Is there is a setting to *force* Ubuntu to move focus on opening a new application?

Note: I am using multiple desktops and 2 monitors if that is relevant

Comment: It is chromium-webbrowser, right? is it only with chromium?

Comment: Yes, only with chromium-webbrowser, other programs take focus as expected

Comment: updated script; there were a few errors.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome in just one monitor and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `dconf` and setting org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences auto-raise to true will do the same thing.

or on commandline:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences auto-raise true
```

This is helpful if you dont want to install compiz

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1857163. It basically requires accessing CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) and setting "Focus Prevention Level" in General Options to "None".